# Problems with UIScrollView in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiscrollview, xcode11

I've got the following Screen Layout:

[image]

**Description Body**, as well as **Requirments Body**, are strings returned by an API that do **not have a fixed length** - I can thus not provide a fixed height and have set `numberOfLines = 0`.

I've tried to embed the Description and Requirements section into a single UIScrollView but so far failed with whichever approach I've taken to accomplish that.

All other posts on stackoverflow seem to be outdated and do not take the Content- and Frame Layout for UIScrollViews, as introduced by Apple in Xcode 11 into consideration.

Can anyone let me know the steps I need to take in interface builder to achieve my goal here?
Note: Want to add further elements below Requirements Body and inside the ScrollView still but first wanted to sort the general problem of not being able to scroll. So if there's anything I would have to consider when adding further elements to the ScrollView later, I'd appreciate if you could let me know as well.

Many thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Since i cannot see any constraints to bottom. Did you try to set any?

Comment: @Teetz: I've tried to embed `Campaign Description View` together with `Campaign Requirements View` into a Vertical Stack. Then embedded that stack into a UIScrollView and added a constraint to bottom - i.e. aligning the bottom of the stack with the bottom of the ScrollView, the latter pinned to the SuperView. Didn't work either.

Comment: Here is a nice tutorial and it is updated for iOS 13: https://www.raywenderlich.com/5758454-uiscrollview-tutorial-getting-started

The key with the "new scrollView layout" is to use the scrollview (and not the frame layout guide) when pinning elements. I would recommend to use one "ContentView" where you put everything in - that makes handling easier. - Hope it helps!

Comment: @BernhardEngl can you elaborate on the "didn't work"? Can you tell us the constraints you set for the ScrollView?

Comment: @Do2: Here's how everything looks right now: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DDWFCHPSR2uX_1QNwiiZfcGCw-y4mEAB/view?usp=sharing - what I mean with "didn't work" is that there's no scrolling, even though I've filled Description body with much more dummy text then the screen can hold. Something on the constraint-side must be screwed but I'm struggling to identify what.

Comment: @BernhardEngl I can't see a height constraint for your ScrollView?

Comment: @Do2: Does it need a fixed height? It's got leading, trailing, top and bottom constraints.

Comment: @BernhardEngl yes it needs a height constraint. Not necessarily fixed, you can put it proportionate height to the parent view. Put equal width = 1 and equal height = 0.6

Comment: @Do2: Getting closer :-) Did as you suggested. Result now looks like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B0nmOB7z8i53JLQUDyFxmwfpccE1Sl6s/view?usp=sharing - Lorem Ipsum Text scrolls horizontally instead of expanding vertically and pushing the Requirements section down on the Y-axis. Believe we're almost there. Do you know what's still missing?

Comment: @BernhardEngl - Based on the images you linked to in your comments, you may need only to add one constraint to your `Scrollable Elements Stack`... Constrain its Width equal to the scroll view's Frame Layout Guide Width, with a constant of `-40` (you have 20-pts padding on each side). That *should* do it.

Comment: @BernhardEngl - oh... your scroll view does ***not*** need a height constraint. You have its Top constrained to the bottom of the "date container view" and its Bottom constrained to the bottom of the view. So no `0.629464 * height` needed.

Comment: @DonMag: So you're saying I should ADD `Scrollable Elements Stack.width = Frame Layout Guide.width + 40` and REMOVE `Scroll View.height = 0.629464 × height`?

Comment: @BernhardEngl - yes, REMOVE the height constraint.... yes, ADD the width constraint... but **minus** 40 (`-40`) not + 40.

Comment: @DonMag: Hmm - looks like this then and does not scroll: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-NyRgmLidWMUm-E8uc85unAIME512bRc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @BernhardEngl - Hmmm... the constraints *look* correct. Can you post / share the source to your storyboard?

Comment: @DonMag: Nothing fancy in there. Still pretty naked. Just pumping some dummy content into some IBOutlets.

Comment: @BernhardEngl - right... I mean share either the `.storyboard` file itself, or `open as -> source code` and share the xml source for it (not the viewController code).

Comment: @DonMag: Ah - ok... put the relevant scene here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pVHp1_A0uvaE-lI3s4Q4l2oCcBCPYA1k/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Ugh... sometimes that works, sometimes Xcode doesn't like it. Take a look here: https://github.com/DonMag/BernhardEngl ... compare how I have the elements constrained with how yours are constrained.

Comment: @DonMag: OMG - overwhelmed by what you did to help me! A million thanks!!! I'll have to look through all the constraints in both projects with a fresh mind tomorrow. Something tells me I'll have to wipe mine and start from scratch :) I'll be back with feedback. Thank you soooo much again!!!

Comment: @DonMag: It finally worked. Ended up re-creating most of the constraints from scratch, sticking to your example. I wish I could clearly point out which one made the difference but can't. The funny thing is that Xcode is now even complaining about height ambiguity for elements in the Scroll Stack being >= 120, which it didn't before when it didn't work and which it doesn't in your example where it's done the exact same way. Can't help but feel that Xcode isn't exactly rock-solid here and already afraid of putting more elements into the ScrollView :-) Thank you so much again for your help!!!!!

Comment: @DonMag: Not sure if you're doing that kind of thing but a post about it on Medium or a video on YouTube or so would definitely get a lot of attention - none of the ones out there (and it feels like I've read 'em all...) is really hitting it.

Comment: @BernhardEngl - one thing that is not always obvious is the (occasional) need to set Content Hugging and/or Compression Resistance priorities. That may be why you're still getting a height ambiguity. I've considered writing some blog / medium posts or making videos, but just never get around to it :)